# How To Bind ListView Index

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a ListView which displays images and index numbers

```
<ListView x:Name="ImageList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PictureEntires, Mode=OneWay}">
...
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IndexImageInTheImageListView}" HorizontalAlignment="..."/>
        <Image ... HorizontalAlignment="..."/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is the challenge:
The ItemSource is from ViewModel.
But the TextBlock needs a Text which comes from different source (e.g. CodeBehind). I need this TextBlock to displays the index of the image in the listview.

Why do I need the index?
Because with this index I want to manipulate the HorizontalAllignment. If the Index is odd number. The index will be displayed on the right side, and the image on the left side.

I know already how to align  those elements as long as I get the index number.

For example:

### ListView

0 Image: Cat

Image: Dog 1

2 Image: Fish

So far I just know how to print out the index. But I can't bind the item with its index

```
        private void ImageListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in TimelineListView.Items)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(TimelineListView.Items.IndexOf(item));

        }
    }
```

Comment: You could try to use a ValueConverter?

Comment: Please refer this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/014069ab-4012-4590-9d23-b39d67f8809b/uwpxamlaccessing-an-items-index-in-an-itemscontrols-itemtemplate?forum=wpdevelop).